# Error opening USB Cam with OpenCV4: GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed

Tags: python, webcam

After installing OpenCV4.0 on my RPi, i tried a simple script below with a Logitech USB Cam (720p) but at "cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)" it gives me an error "(python:num process): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed"

```
import cv2

print('Start')

# initialize the camera
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, image = cam.read()

if ret:
    cv2.imshow('SnapshotTest',image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyWindow('SnapshotTest')
    cv2.imwrite('/home/pi/SnapshotTest.jpg',image)

cam.release()
print('End')
```

Has anyone a clue why this happen?

Thanks!

Edit April 30th:
Let me add that if I unplug my USB Cam from RPi then I have the following message:
Then when I unplug the USB Cam, the process get out of hang state and return the following message:
"VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by OpenCV
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: can't open camera by index 0
VIDIOC_REQBUFS: No such device"